# Failed an audit for flagging as duplicate that looks legit to me

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

As I can see at https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22647172, I failed an audit. That does not look legit to me: I flagged that question as a duplicate, as another user also did. The answers that were already posted at the question in that audit contain the exact same solutions as in the question I linked in the duplicate.

Can anyone explain what I did wrong here? Flagging as duplicate looks legit to me

Comment: @gnat thanks for pointing that out - so it was really a failure of me tagging this as a duplicate, while I still think it is?

Comment: That definitely looks like a dupe, albeit slightly different (in terms of the color style), but `filter` is mentioned in the linked dupe as is a myriad of other methods.

Comment: I don't want to start an argument about whether this **really** is a duplicate after all, but whether having this question as an audit is fine, as it might cause false positives

Comment: The TL;DR here is the question is 1. Open 2. Highly upvoted, which makes it an audit target, sadly (Close Queue audits work the same way). You just got caught by an unintentional trap is all

Comment: *"Nico Haase reviewed this 4 hours ago: Unsalvageable"* Unsalvageable is the result of voting to close as a dupe? Man, audits are so terrible.